# Usage and omission of "any"

Tags: determiners

Can I omit **any** in the following sentences with uncountable nouns? Do they still sound natural without it?

- If philosophers were made presidents instead of politicians, there would not be (**any**) war.
- If we keep on wasting drinking water like this, in future there will not be (**any**) drinking water.

Can any teacher or expert please answer this?

Answer (score 1):

Those would still be *grammatically valid* sentences with the omissions of "any", but "any" provides some particular emphasis, so the revised sentences would not necessarily have the exact same *meaning*.

> If philosophers were made presidents instead of politicians, there would not be **any** war.

In the first example, the sentence *without* "any" might be understood as "there would not be a war as a direct consequence of the proposed situation." However, the sentence *with* "any" clearly expresses that **no more war will exist** ***at all***.

The second example would likely have the same understood meaning with or without "any". However, "any" is used to strongly emphasize the dire situation that a complete lack of drinking water would be.